# Extending style object in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using react.js and manage most of the style attributes via react, too. If I have a, for example, a success and an error button I want to apply a different background color to them.

Right now, I'm doing this with jQuery's extend function:

```
<span style={$.extend({background: 'forestgreen'},this.state.buttonStyle)}></span>
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better and maybe more readable solution for this. Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a transpiler that implements the [spread property proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) (such as Babel), you can write

```
style={{...this.state.buttonStyle, background: 'forestgreen'}}
```

instead.

Whether thats "better" or more readable is likely subjective.

Comment: I use Babel, so I will give this a try. No need for jQuery anymore then.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Object.assign` if you polyfill it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Object.assign sounds good, but it seems to be unsupported by any browser but firefox - do I get this wrong?

Comment: That's why I said you'd have to polyfill it. Babel does this as well with the right config.

Comment: OK, now I see. Thank you!

Comment: Just merging objects is not enough when working with objects that contain CSS styles. There are shorthand properties, different letter casing etc which should be handled in correct order by the merging function. I'm looking for and haven't found yet a library that provides such a function.

Comment: Here's a library that does shorthand property expansion: https://github.com/kapetan/css-shorthand-expand , but this is not a complete solution.

Comment: Does Object.assign do recursive copy in depth as jQuery.extend({}, true, ...) ?

Comment: @FernandoGabrieli: No.